# Use both claims and classic authentication in the same web application SharePoint 2010

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-foundation, claims-based-auth, classic-mode-auth

We have a webapplication that uses claims authentication.

We want to alternate between claims and classic authentication, depending on the user location, Ip, gps coordnates, etc.

Is it possible to have both authentication methods working at the same time? How?

From what I've been searching we can extend the webapplication and define which kind of authentication is used based on the zones, but is there any other way ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to have claims and classic authentication at the same time on a web application.

If you are using claims-authentication, you can specify multiple authentication providers on one zone; or extend your web app to multiple zones, and use one authentication provider per zone.

For instance, Windows-authentication (NTLM) on the Default zone, and SAML-authentication on the Intranet zone (typically ADFS).

Note: I don't understand why you want to offer classic or claims authentication to your users based on IP address. I think you misunderstood something about what claims authentication is (it is not limited to authentication with ADFS).

Comment: Yeah, that's what I was suspecting, thanks. Regarding your note: client's requests.