# Change only one of my webapplications to Claims Based Auth in SP2013?

Tags: claims-based-auth

In my Scenario i have got 5 webapplications and a lot of user i daily use.
I have to change all webapplications to Claims based auth but first i wish to change only one af the Webapplications to Claims based auth, to check if it works with my ADFS server.
Is it possible to do the change to only one af the webapplications, without disturbing all the users on the other webapplications?

Comment: Now when i use the Convert-SpWebApplication i get the warning: This operation will trigger user migration....Does it migrate all users in my farm or does it migrate only the users that are connected in this webapplication? And if my useraccount is migrated, will i be able to connect to the other webapplications, that still is Windows auth. after my account is migrated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typically Claims is web application scoped, so there is no technical problem running only one webapp in claims mode.

However, I'd backup content database and keep solutions handy before testing in acceptance test with the following PowerShell script

```
Convert-SPWebApplication -Identity "http://WebAppURL" -To Claims -RetainPermissions [-Force]
```

More to read:

- [Migrate from classic-mode to claims-based authentication in SharePoint 2013](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg251985.aspx)
- [Convert-SPWebApplication](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj219696.aspx)

Comment: Now when i use the Convert-SpWebApplication i get the warning: This operation will trigger user migration....Does it migrate all users in my farm or does it migrate only the users that are connected in this webapplication? And if my useraccount is migrated, will i be able to connect to the other webapplications, that still is Windows auth. after my account is migrated?

Comment: @SteenKarlshøj Yes you will. SharePoint don't actually authenticate users, that is the job for your Identity provider (read Active Directory). You can easely check this if you set a test user password as expired, SharePoint won't let your user inside. The Convert-SPWebApplication cmdlet just tells your web application that the authentication *method* is claims instead of Clacssic (LEGACY). And the authentication *method* this web application uses after you run the script is Claims, at the same time when other web applications use Classic.

Comment: However, you can't use Claims and Classic in the same webapp, as asked here: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/122565/use-both-claims-and-classic-authentication-in-the-same-web-application-sharepoin